# How to Create Dynamic TableLayout with three customized button in android

Tags: android

I want to create a dynamic table whose row uses customized button which uses selector.xml file and I am not getting how to do it.

Plz Help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is hard to understand.  Please give an example of what you're trying to do, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Bill What I want is that I want to create a dynamic tablelayout layout whose table row has a button.The button is customized by selector.xml file which is used for selecting button images at instances button is pressed and released.But I am not getting how can I use those file at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Inflate your layout which you want to use as a table row and by inflating you can use your customized buttons

Comment: thank you,for reply i am waiting from few days to someone answer this question,from this suggestion my query is solved.thank u.